# Difference in response headers - Normal Service vs Through Jetties reverse ProxyServlet

Tags: java, jetty, reverse-proxy, embedded-jetty

I am using standalone jetty application as reverse proxy, While sending a request to a service directly without using reverse proxy application, I get the following response headers with the response.

- Content-Type →application/xml
- Transfer-Encoding →chunked
- Server →Jetty(9.3.8.v20160314)

When sending the same request using reverse proxy application, I get the following response headers with the response

- Date →Fri, 04 Jan 2019 08:12:41 GMT
- Content-Type →application/xml
- Server →Jetty(9.3.8.v20160314)
- Content-Length →460

The problem is that I get content-length header here instead of Transfer-Encoding. So whether reverse proxy does not send the response chunked or it stores the entire response and forwards it entirely.

Comment: Both of those are valid HTTP/1.1 responses that follow RFC7230.  There's nothing wrong with either response.

Comment: Yes, both the responses are valid, My question is whether the response is stored and forwarded when using jetty as reverse proxy - @JoakimErdfelt